# Flot Chart - How to show very first and last month on x Axis with minTickSize: [2, "month"]

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

Trying to show the name of very first and last month on x-axis. 
Plus, the x axis has the following option

```
minTickSize: [2, "month"] .
```

So ,  basically the x axis shows Feb, April, June, ... and so on. 
I would like it to start with the first month value in the data set. 
How could I enable that ?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shamaleyte/6gL1wzsL/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data has one datapoint per month but always at 19:44 on the 14th.
The tick for your first month (December) would be on December 1th which is not in your data range. Possible solutions:

- Change min and max values to the first day of a month (example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gL1wzsL/7/)):

  ```
  min: 1417388400000,
  max: 1427925600000
  ```
- Change the dates in your data to the first day of the month.
- Use the category plugin / mode instead of time mode.

Comment: Raidri, is there any way of automatically setting of min-max value based on the data-set available?    I do not know the first and last timestamp specifically  in the data-set. And It could change from time to time .That's why I cannot set it manually.  The first thing came to my mind is writing a custom function to detect the first day of a month of the first and last time stamp. What do you suggest ?

Comment: Yes, you have to write a custom function for that. And for the last timestamp you have to calculate the second day of the next month like in my example if you want to see that last tick.